# Google maps Android API getting wifi location

Tags: android, geolocation, wifi, google-maps-android-api-2

So I am working on this app that will get the location of a wifi hotspot by just detecting it using the sensor wifi of the phone (The phone is not actually connecting to the hotspot wifi, it just detect).
I was doing some preliminary research before start developing the app, and it seems that the Google Geolocation API will do the work for me. However, it is not free (at least what I understood after reading through the API). I had checked other apps that detects wifi hotspot, and I am just wondering if those apps have their own database with all the wifi hotspot information  (SSID, location coordinates, etc) so when the wifi sensor detects a wifi hotspot, it will lookup the database and get the information such as location. 
Also, I was mentioned by a colleague that Google Maps also stores wifi info. Is is true? Cause I couldn't find any info about that.

Answer (score 3):

Android has multiple LocationProviders, including:

- `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` : get position using GPS
- `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` : get position using Wifi, cell network, etc.
- `LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER`: get position using data provided by already running providers. This allows several apps to share geolocation information)

**You don't have to pay anything** to use `NETWORK_PROVIDER`
*Some providers might not be present on all devices, depending on phone model and android version.*

Providers have different characteristics: NETWORK is fast but not always precise enough, GPS is precise but slow and battery intensive, etc. The best strategy is to request location from several providers, and cancel pending request as soon as you get a location that is good enough depending on your criteria (precision, response time, etc.)

I found [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html?m=1) by Reto Meier quite useful to wrap my head around geolocation on Android

Comment: I do know about LocationManager. But what I am trying to do is to get the location of the wifi hotspot spotted using my wifi. But the thing is, I am not connecting to the wifi. I just want to spot any available and try to get a sense of my current location. LocationManager using the NETWORK_PROVIDER will work only if I am connected to a wifi.

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER does **not** require you to be connected to a hotspot at all. It use cell towers, visible SSIDs, and maybe other things to quickly compute an **approximate location of the phone**. If you are trying to get the location of the hotspot, then this is another issue.

Comment: So if I find a list of available wifi spots, then I can get extra information of each of them without making a connection such as SSID, or BSSID. Thanks I think I have an idea now.