# mobile positioning in google maps using only internet

Tags: android, positioning

I used an android smartphone in the following situation:

- without SIM-Card
- connected to a WLAN
- located in an indoor environment (GPS does not work)
- located somewhere other than the address probabely set in google account

for positioning in Google-Maps App. The result was roughly correct (about 15 meters error).

- There is no GPS signals to get position.
- Thre is no SIM-Card. So using Cell ID is impossible.

It means the only resource from which my position is achieved is internet. Could anybody explain to me (while I couldn't find anything in internet) how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google gathers information on the SSID of WiFi hotspots. They drive around with cars gathering street views for their maps and other information like the location of WiFi hotspotes. They store it in a data base somewhere and when you ask for your location it will find out the SSIDs of every WiFi hotspote around you and then give a rough estimate based on signal strength and other information.

Google might use people's cell phones to gather WiFi SSID information as well I am not really sure about that though. I think this because there are setting in most android phones asking to help Google for accuracy using WiFi...

Other sites use public ISP information obtained by IP address but this is not as reliable as it gives the location of your ISP (Internet Service Provider).

[Here is a site where many people are discussing this topic.](https://www.quora.com/How-does-android-use-WiFi-to-get-your-current-location-so-accurately)

[Here is a site that teaches how Google finds location data through SSID](https://askleo.com/if-an-ip-address-doesnt-do-it-then-how-does-google-know-my-location/)

[Here is a site that teaches how geolocation software finds ISP location](http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation)

Comment: Is it still possible if I use internet over sim-card or hotspots are necessary?

Comment: If you are connected using a WiFi hotspot then it will find your location using WiFi hotspot location data. But if you are connected through a sim card that has a working GPS system then it will find your location through GPS. IF one method of finding location is unavailable it will default to what ever method is reachable.

Comment: Consider a  case having no GPS data and WiFi connection but only connecting to the internet over sim-card. If in this case some WiFi networks are detectable but not accessible, is still using SSID technique feasible or access to a WiFi is necessary?

Comment: If you are connected using sim-card and your WiFi is turned off then it will use the ISP location that the sim-card is connected to and will not be as accurate. If your connected through sim-card and your WiFi is on it will still use your WiFi adapter to see what WiFi SSIDs you are close to and use this method to track your location.

Comment: Thanks I got my answere. It would be nice if you add some references for more details

Comment: I added three sources at the bottom of my post. I think they will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Google, apart from other ways, uses SSID of the nearby networks to get your position. AFAIR there was a big concern about Google Street View Cars scanning for wifi networks, recording SSIDs for location purposes. If that SSID is not registered, they probably use some kind of IP location service, based on network provider ip address pool.

See [Google maps Android API getting wifi location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429952/google-maps-android-api-getting-wifi-location) for more details about getting that information from Android.

Answer (score 0):

Android may use wifi and sensors in order to get your position. The more wifi routers around - the more accurate your position.

Comment: Do you mean using triangulation? if yes, it would be helpful only for relative localisation. in my case GPS is inaccessible (I tested in in a seprate app if I receive GPS signals) which means I have not absolute position